# "Take off", "head off", "leave". What else can be used to politely indicate that I am leaving

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I got a feeling that it is rude to say "I'm gonna leave" or "I'm leaving". Is it really impolite?  And the term "take off", I have only seen it used on the series "Friends". Most of the time, it is used for the departure of a flight. So the only option I have now is head off, but it seems informal. Well, you can't expect me to say "I'm gonna boost" on a formal occasion. So, what else could be used to inform others that I am leaving?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Interpersonal.Stackexchange.

Comment: It depends entirely on circumstances. Casual: "Well, it's time I was on my way." Practical: "I have to go and pick up my children now." Polite: "Would you excuse me?" etc. etc.

Comment: @Peter Shor _That_'s the one. Keep forgetting it. Could be on the CV-reason alongside  ELU Meta, ELL, [also Computer Science, Language Learning, Linguistics, Literature, Writing, Puzzling].

Comment: Be aware that "I got" is ungrammatical as a present-tense form. Another concern is perhaps more important: are you truly unaware that writing *gonna* is a way of signalling to others that you don't care about the actual spelling rules of written English? Or was flouting those rules your deliberate intent? In any case, this is certainly something that some readers find offensive and off-putting. It's like going to church and spouting profane curses left and right. It's considered rude there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing rude about the word "leave". What might be impolite about saying

> I'm leaving now,

is not the word "leave", but the fact that you're leaving abruptly in the middle of something without apologizing for it. You could say

> I'm really sorry, but I need to leave now,

or

> I wish I could stick around, but I have to go,

or something similar.

You can be much, much ruder than "I'm leaving". For example,

> I'm bored with this stupid game. I'm gonna cut and run.

Given that the answer to the question has nothing to do with the English language in particular, this probably belongs on Interpersonal.Stackexchange.